# Why are the parentheses around the function AND the argument list?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, anonymous-function

I am watching a [video course on Google Maps](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/custom-interactive-maps-with-the-google-maps-api) which has the following code in a `script.js` file which is referenced from within the `<head>` tag of the `index.html` file:

```
(function(window, google) {

  // code not shown sets element and
  // options (center, zoom, disableDefaultUI).

  map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

}(window, google))
```

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), as well as [the IIFE pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), I was expecting the outer parentheses to be enveloping the function only, not the argument list, like so:

```
(function(window, google) {
// same exact code here as shown above.
})(window, google)
```

I tried both and they both work and display the map.  I have not been able to find a reference to the first, envelope-everything approach.  Is it just a minor variation of the same pattern?

Comment: Yes, it is the variation for the same pattern. (IIFE)

Comment: The two forms behave in exactly the same way.

Comment: In particular see the answer in the linked question from @令狐葱

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's it, thank you! rajuGT, thank you.